# error installing perl module Net::SSH::Perl

Tags: perl, cpan

*emphasized text*While installing perl module "Net::SSH::Perl" using `perl -MCPAN -e "install Net::SSH::Perl"` is not showing any error only `Result:PASS` but using `cpan -D Net::SSH::Perl` showing not installed. What is the reason for not getting installed.

Comment: I tried to install `Net::SSH::Perl` on Ubuntu 20.04, perl 5.30 with `cpanm Net::SSH::Perl` but the installation of the dependency `Crypt::Curve25519` failed (I am looking into it)

Comment: See also [this](https://github.com/ajgb/crypt-curve25519/issues/9) issue

Comment: You can just use `cpan Net::SSH::Perl` to install the module.

Answer (score 2):

I was able to install the module after patching the dependent module `Crypt::Curve25519` like this.

First create a patch `Crypt-Curve25519-0.06-missing-version.patch`:

```
diff --git a/lib/Crypt/Curve25519.pm b/lib/Crypt/Curve25519.pm
index 686b706..d9c2b3d 100644
--- a/lib/Crypt/Curve25519.pm
+++ b/lib/Crypt/Curve25519.pm
@@ -1,4 +1,5 @@
 package Crypt::Curve25519;
+our $VERSION = 0.06;
 #ABSTRACT: Generate shared secret using elliptic-curve Diffie-Hellman function

 use strict;
```

Then, run:

```
wget https://www.cpan.org/authors/id/S/SR/SREZIC/patches/Crypt-Curve25519-0.06-PR10-ANOTHERLINK.patch
git clone git@github.com:ajgb/crypt-curve25519.git
cd crypt-curve25519
git apply ../Crypt-Curve25519-0.06-missing-version.patch
git apply ../Crypt-Curve25519-0.06-PR10-ANOTHERLINK.patch
perl Makefile.PL
make  # No errors now
make test
make install
cpanm Net::SSH::Perl
```

Comment: I'm trying to build this for a Docker container that only connects to one specific machine. Is this module truly needed or is there a way to skip this dependency and have it still "work". If for example, the host I'm connecting to does not use curve25519 in any way.